# How to use @Entity attribute when inheritance is across separate JARs?

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa-2.0

I have two entities where one of them inherits the other one, so I have in **jar1** the **entity1** and I have a **jar2** the **entity2->inherits(entity1)**

in jar1:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {...}
```

in jar2:

```
@Entity
public class Entity2 extends Entity1 {...}
```

So how can I make this to work, it doesn't even compile saying:

```
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.discoverMappedSuperclassesAndInheritanceParents(EntityAccessor.java:224)
```

It seems simple, but it does not work, what should I do?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the persistencel.xml for jar2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns /persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="EntityBPU" transaction-type="JTA">
   <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
   <jta-data-source>my_datasource</jta-data-source>
   <jar-file>jar1.jar</jar-file>
   <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
   </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: That sure doesn't look like a compile error.

Comment: Yes, it is a compiler error because it does not compile.

Comment: How do you build your archive, where do you put your JARs with entities, how does your `persistence.xml` file look like?

Comment: Hello @PiotrNowicki, all jars are in the same folder and the persistence.xml for both files are the basic created by Netbeans 7.0, I will publish it in a moment.

Comment: Please do not repost the same question. Edit it instead like others have suggested. I'm closing your original version as a duplicate of this one this time, but keep this in mind in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @AnnaLear, thanks for the tip, I was already told earlier.

Comment: @PiotrNowicki already published the persistence.xml

Comment: @AnnaLear, what's the point of modifying a post if it's not inserted in the post queue (just tested it), how is it suposed people is going to see it again to find a possible answer?

Comment: Is it WAR or EAR? What is the exact location of these files? Show us also *where* in jar2 did you define your `persistence.xml`.

Comment: @Joe Editing a post will bump it and get fresh eyes on it.

Comment: Sorry @AnnaLear, but that's not true, I already tested that strategy and the question is not inserted anywhere, and here it's with the same views and still unanswered. So when you have the time, please give us a demo to see how you do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically there's nothing special about having two related entities in different JARs.

Check your environment and the way you compile.

Comment: Hello @Oleg, yes it should compile I have made clean builds and checked the environment but still doesn't work. If I place the files in the same jar then it works, but the point is I can not place everything in the same jar. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am not sure, I have struggled with this for a while and cannot find a solution for this. Keeping this unique jar is not letting the system to grow properly and cannot granulate the functionality as expected either.